# Slick plain SQL vs. Anorm

Tags: scala, slick, anorm

Provided that the goal is to use plain SQL for queries/statements, are there anything significant differences in capabilities between Anorm and Slick plainSQL.

Comment: Abouts facts, even if Typesafe has pro support for Slick, Anorm is still part of Playframework organisation, with community support. Aside from that's I think answers would be quite opinionated, as you should be able to achieve same goals with Slick Plain SQL or Anorm. In my mind, if you prefer writing the SQL statements by yourself mapping the results, then Anorm would be my choice (!! quite subjective choice).

Answer (score 3):

Slick uses an asynchronous API (Scala's `Futures`) while Anorm is synchronous. You can easily `Await` `Futures` returend from Slick's. However, going asynchronous with Anorm would be more challenging.

Answer (score 1):

Slick and Anorm are now equal choices for Play (since Anorm has been moved into a module). Play-slick is another module officially supported by the play framework team and Typesafe.

As I hear Anorms result parser is interesting to some people. Slick supports type-safe sql strings since 3.0.0. Apart from that many things are probably equally powerful, but have a different syntax. Slick uses Scala's String interpolation, Anorm seems to have their own interpolation solution, probably because it is older.